# Visualize enum value

Tags: c, enums

How can i visualize the types of food with type enum?

```
typedef struct cat{
 int code;
 int age;
 float weight;
 enum {kibbles,canned_food,tuna_fish}food;
} cats;

int n,i;

printf("Insert a number: ");
scanf("%d",&n);

cats *cat_arr = calloc(n, sizeof(cats));

for(i = 0;i<n;i++){
    printf("Code: ");
    scanf("%d",&cat_arr[i].code);
    printf("Age: ");
    scanf("%d",&cat_arr[i].age);
    printf("weight: ");
    scanf("%f",&cat_arr[i].weight);
    printf("Food: ");
    scanf("%d",&cat_arr[i].food);
}


for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    if(cat_arr[i].age < 4 && cat_arr[i].weight > avg){
        printf("%d %s",cat_arr[i].code,cat_arr[i].food);   <---- HERE
    }
}
```

I want insert type of food with numbers and display the name that i assigned with enum.

Comment: You cannot do that without magic. This is a typical thing where it's probably best to not try to solve it. Just live with that it's not doable. Or switch to another language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no automatic way to get the string equivalent of an enum constant.  You'll need to create a mapping of enums to their string equivalents and reference that.

```
const char *food_names[] = { "kibbles" , "canned_food" ,"tuna_fish" };

...

printf("%d %s", cat_arr[i].code, food_names[cat_arr[i].food]);
```

Comment: So what is the utility of enum?

Comment: @Boninissimo To assign symbolic names to a related set of numeric constants.

Comment: Well, it might not be fully automatic i guess, but using the preprocessor you can at least populate the string array without having to type out the names yourself (as demonstrated in my answer)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do that in a somewhat automated way, you'll need to use some preprocessor-magic:

```
#define FOOD(X) \
        X(kibbles), \
        X(canned_food), \
        X(tuna_fish)

#define EXPAND_AS_ENUM(a)     a
#define EXPAND_AS_STRING(a)  #a

enum
{
    FOOD(EXPAND_AS_ENUM)
} food;

const char* food_names[] =
{
    FOOD(EXPAND_AS_STRING)
}
```

This way, you'll get an enum and the corresponding string-array with matching names

Answer (score -1):

It's hard to get what you wxactly mean but if you want to get enum name from index then:

```
struct Type{
    enum Err{
        not_found = 0,
        internet = 1
    }
    std::string get( int index ){
        if(index == 0) return "not_found";
        if(index == 1) return "internet";
    }
};
```

Then call the get function with index as argument

Comment: There is no std::string in C (and of course you also can't define a function within a struct)

Comment: then change std::string to array of char and then define the same function in global scope which recive another param as the struct Type;

Comment: @SudipGhimire Or change the answer so that it works in C?