# How can i get an enum value from a file?

Tags: c

Let's say i've a .txt file where i store a list of patient with their personal data.

```
Region   Unique Hospital Code  Surname  Name      FiscalCode/ID   Patient Status

  X           006              Rossi    Mario    RSSRMA56B76B249P       0
```

This is my enum

```
enum patientStatus {
    HomeCare=0,
    HospitalCare,
    SubIntensiveCare,
    IntensiveCare,
    Recovered
};
```

Should i use %d to print that enum?

Comment: you deleted your question about TS Error handling. Check this out: https://patrickroza.com/blog/when-to-return-a-result-error-and-when-to-throw-an-exception/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd always save the stringified form of the enumerator value to a file, e.g. `"HomeCare"`, `"HospitalCare"`, &c.

In this way you guard against the `enum` values having a different backing type, or even being reordered during program refactoring. And one can read the file too without having to consult a manual.

Of course there will be some overhead in converting the string into the enumerator, so there's some work to do there. But performance wise, I/O will still be the bottleneck.

Comment: This should provide the best portability, as long as the strings aren't changed at some point. Additionally, macros can be used to guarantee consistency between values and names in the source code, as i've demonstrated in my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61344384/visualize-enum-value/61344536#61344536)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the size that `enum` variables has on your specific system. They are not portable - this is compiler-specific. `enum` variables may be the same as `sizeof(int)` or they may be smaller.

For this reason it might be wise to convert them to a portable `uint32_t` before writing them to a file, and then read them as `uint32_t` and convert back to `enum` from there.

Comment: ... to a portable `uint_least32_t`?

Comment: @pmg That would be less portable, yeah? Because there's no guarantee that it corresponds with the size of an enum. I think the compiler is even allowed to use different enum sizes on different enum types, in the same program.

Comment: Maybe, I was just thinking of the possibility of an implementation to leave `uint32_t` undefined (but it must define `uint_least32_t`)

Comment: @pmg Implementations that don't support "optional" `uint32_t` are hopelessly broken and should not be used.

Comment: Maybe quantum computing will bring *strange* platforms to the realm of C soon(ish) :)

Comment: @pmg Yep we'll have quantum computers long before we have a sound replacement for the C language.